# Not able to read corpus from XML in R because of unexpected tags in XML file

Tags: xml, r, parsing

This is the piece of code where I am getting error:

```
myXMLReader <- readXML(
  spec = list(Content = list("node", "/DOC/TEXT"),
              ID = list("node", "/DOC/DOCNO")),
  doc = PlainTextDocument())
corpusF <- paste(basepath,"corpus",sep="")
myCorpus <- Corpus(DirSource(corpusF),readerControl = list(reader = myXMLReader))
```

and the error I am getting is:

```
Error: 1: Opening and ending tag mismatch: a0 line 5 and TEXT
2: Opening and ending tag mismatch: a0 line 5 and DOC
3: Premature end of data in tag a0 line 5
4: Premature end of data in tag a0 line 5
5: Premature end of data in tag TEXT line 4
6: Premature end of data in tag DOC line 2
```

Actually I am trying to read XML file here. When I ran the same code in my Mac it ran perfectly but I am getting this error in Ubuntu.
So far what I have figured out is: if I read the XML file which is causing the error and convert it into text files, in few places instead of blank space M- is appearing and that's why R is telling that there is premature end of data in tag.
My question is, why is the same code able to read XML files correctly while the other cannot and how to fix this problem? Is this issue with language of the environment and how XML file is read in that environment?

Comment: Sounds like potentially an issue with file encoding. The "M-" is likely an indication of a different line ending between the two systems. Is this a really old Mac? Usually file endings between macs and linux machines are fine since OS X; it's usually when you are moving files between Windows and Mac/linux that you have problems.

Comment: I have a brand new Mac. To make everything clear:
1) I am working on a standard dataset available online (all XML files), so there is no issue of moving the files.
2) I ran the code on my mac and two ubuntu systems. In one of the Ubuntu system I am getting the above error while in the other and also in my mac, the code is running fine. I converted the XML files into text files only to check if there is any special character in the file which might be invisible in XML format; I am not reading txt files but .xml files.